# How to configure Eclipse PyDev PYTHONPATH to work with Vagrant?

Tags: eclipse, vagrant, pydev

I have a python project source folder that is compiled inside Vagrant, therefore I don't have any dependency packages (like Django) installed on my machine, they are all inside Vagrant.

Is it possible to have PyDev look for the dependencies inside Vagrant? Right now it cannot find anything and reports tons of errors.

Maybe I could map `site-packages` folder from Vagrant to my local folder and point PyDev there?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this with MacOS like a Host VM and Ubuntu like Vagrant. IMHO I think this is not possible in any case.

The answer is simply: NO.

1. Vagrant is a Virtual Machine with your own file system that is not visible out of there.
2. Different OS have different compiled binaries.
3. Eclipse/PyDev is not capable to view only site-packages, he want only an interpreter location, the rest is Eclipse/PyDev that look for other libraries.

If there is a real solution, please explain me how to...

Comment: I mapped site-packages folder from vagrant debian to my local osx and it works fine, there is no compiled binaries in python. Interpreter location is local.

Comment: The python interpreter is a binary, and if you want a consistent python environment, imho, you must link the bin folder into Pydev and not only the site-packages directory. Pydev search all libraries in autonomous way from this bin folder.

But if linking the site-packages dir solve your question, then it's a good trick :)

You can use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) in macos and all other systems that run python projects, it's a more flexible and consistent solution.